# Make a matrix symmetric and positive semi-definite if it already approximately is

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have a matrix that ought to be symmetric and positive semi-definite (with real entries). However, due to small rounding errors that can accumulate over time, that might not be strictly true. For example, the smallest eigenvalue might be $-10^{-10}$ even though it ought to be $0$ if we had been using exact calculations. This isn't particularly important overall, except that some computations will fail altogether with even this small negative number.

Is there a simple expression that will fix this? As an example of what I'm looking for:

- If I were asking "how do I make a real number non-negative if it already nearly is?" I'd like the answer "take the absolute value". This leaves non-negative numbers precisely unchanged, and only has a small effect on small strictly negative numbers.
- If I were asking "how do I make a matrix $M$ symmetric" I'd like the answer "use $M + M^t$". Actually that is one of the things I want so that will be my first step!
- So what I'm asking, analogously, is: "how do I make the matrix positive semidefinite?"

Comment: $M^T M$ will be positive semi-definite in general as well as being symmetric

Comment: @Henry Thanks for that. I don't think it works in my case, as it won't leave the matrix unchanged if it's already positive semi-definite (e.g. if it's diagonal then it will square the eigenvalues).

Comment: @ArthurTacca Then take $(M^T M)^{1/2}$. Note that this is actually commonly denoted 
as $|M|$.

Comment: @Rammus Oh that's perfect. Often the next thing I do is take the square root anyway, so I could simply do $(M^T M)^{1/4}$ (I don't even need to make it symmetric first, as Henry said). If you post your comment as an answer (with a hint of why $|M| = M$ if it was already positive semidefinite - I think it would do to note that it follows from the diagonalisation $M = P^TDP$ so $M^T M = P^TD^2P$ and then the square root just square roots the entries of $D$) then I'll accept that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible method is to take the operator
$$
|M| = (M^T M)^{1/2}.
$$
This is a positive semidefinite matrix whose eigenvalues are the singular values of $M$. For example, if $M$ is a symmetric matrix then $|M|$ is a symmetric matrix matrix whose eigenvalues are the absolute value of the eigenvalues of $M$. Indeed, if $M$ is symmetric then let $M = U D U^T$ be the spectral decomposition of $M$ where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix and $D$ is diagonal. Then
$$
|M| = ((UDU^T)^T (UDU^T))^{1/2} = (UDU^T U DU^T)^{1/2} = U(D^2)^{1/2}U^T = U |D| U^T.
$$
It also follows then that if $M$ is already positive semidefinite then $|M| = M$.

If you want this to work in general for matrices acting on $\mathbb{C}^n$ then you can also take $|M| = (M^* M)^{1/2}$ where $~^*$ indicates the conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 2):

If all you care about is positive **semi**definite, the bluntest instrument you can use is:

First, symmetrize, as you suggest, to produce a new matrix $S.$

Second, take the pseudo-inverse $P$ of S (`np.linalg.pinv` if you are using python, with a reasonable cutoff (say $1.0e-6$), and then the pseudo-inverse $Q$ of $P.$
Then, Q will be the matrix you seek. Or at least *A* matrix you seek.

A more direct (though not faster) method is write your $S = P^t D P,$ where $P$ is orthogonal, D diagonal, and clip the negative entries of $D$ to $0.$ It will produce the same result as above.

Comment: OK thanks. The operation I'm planning to do next is not far off decomposing into $P^t D P$ anyway, so I might as well do that, clip the negative values of $D$ like you say, and go directly from there. (By the way is there a name for that decomposition, or especially for $(\sqrt{D}P)^t (\sqrt{D}P)$ when $S$ is positive semidefinite? A little off topic but much appreciated if you know.)

Comment: By the way I will leave the question open just a little longer before accepting your answer.

Comment: @ArthurTacca Not sure if there is a name, but this construction happens all the time (for example, to show that any PSD matrix is a Gram matrix).

Comment: Thanks Igor, but I accepted the answer by Rammus in the end as a little closer to what I was looking for. By the way, $P^tDP$ could simply be described as "diagonalising the matrix" or (as Rammus said) the "spectral decomposition".

Comment: @ArthurTacca You are certainly free to accept any answer you like, but I don't actually think the other scheme does the right thing: The negative eigenvalues are junk, so why take their absolute value instead of throwing them away?

Comment: I think I just like the smoothness of the answer. I feel like it's also safer (although that might just be my paranoia and lack of understanding at work): doesn't finding the (pseudo)inverse or eigenvalue decomposition fail sometimes if a matrix is not positive semidefinite? There's no risk of that with $M^tM$.

Comment: @ArthurTacca First of all, no, it does not fail, and second, even if it did, that is not a reason to choose an obviously wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix $M$ is "nearly" positive semi-definite then the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ is just below zero. Hence, If $I$ is the identity matrix, $M+\epsilon I$ should be positive semi-definite with smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_1+\epsilon\geq 0$ (I guess finding the smallest epsilon as to not perturb your matrix too much is the hard job).